# Can Visual Stuidos be used to develop in C++ and still create a program capable of running on Mac?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, posix

For C++ development I noticed Visual Studios 2013 sort of forces the Microsoft extension onto you and I'm wondering if there's any settings that should be disabled if one is coding for maximum portability? For example when a new source file is added it comes with `_tmain()` which clearly isn't standard C++. In the following screen what should be selected if one wants to program for Mac, since it wouldn't be a Win32 application? I'm afraid intelitype is going to mess things up by suggesting things not in the C++ standard.

[image: screen shot]

I've decided to reopne this question as it seems to have been misunderstood. For example, when I used visual studio I could use the macro "EXIT_SUCCESS" and make calls to `sin()` and `cos()` without including any additional libraries. I could also define `const public PI = 3.14159` in the header file. These 3 things wouldn't compile on another computer using g++. So what must I change in Visual Studios?

Comment: `_tmain()` certainly isn't POSIX! Your question is muddleheaded.

Comment: It is just a macro.  They work on any operating system.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a compiler that can compile for your desired mac platform.

Writing portable c++ code means your code will work as intended for that compiler too.

VS 2013 can surely build with several different compilers. It likely ships with a Win only compiler.   The _tmain is a microsoft c++ extension, but is by no means a Windows extension.

Edit: Adding that intellisense won't suggest stuff that you haven't indicated you need. #includes and stuff add to intellisense.  It is quite clever about that.